# Downtime when k8s terminates old pods after deploying to GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Sometimes (not always) my app goes down when Kubernetes starts terminating old pods. It returns the HTTP 500 status as PHP cannot connect to SQL Proxy's sidecar container.

It all happens less often now, but I notice it still does. My last attempts have been to add livenessProbe and readinessProbe to the containers and include a preStop hook to make Apache quit gracefully. Plus adding a big terminationGracePeriodSeconds and adding the `-term_timeout=2000s` parameter to Cloud SQL Proxy trying to keep it alive  some more minutes.

Shouldn't all this make the old pod go away in peace? What else is missing? My k8s manifest is the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  minReadySeconds: 60
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: myapp
    spec:
      readinessGates:
        - conditionType: "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 2000
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: [my image URL goes here]
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 11 && /usr/sbin/apachectl graceful-stop" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 1Gi
            cpu: 500m
          limits:
            memory: 1Gi
            cpu: 500m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /admin/
            port: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /admin/
            port: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
              path: /admin/
              port: 80
      - name: cloud-sql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.27.1-alpine
        command:
          - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
          - "-instances=myproject-development:southamerica-east1:mysql8-testing=tcp:3306"
          - "-term_timeout=2000s"
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
        startupProbe:
            exec:
              command: ["nc", "-z", "127.0.0.1", "3306"]
        readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command: ["nc", "-z", "127.0.0.1", "3306"]
        livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command: ["nc", "-z", "127.0.0.1", "3306"]
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu:    "1"
---
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2beta1"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: "myapp-hpa"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    run: "myapp"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: "myapp"
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 7
  metrics:
  - type: "Resource"
    resource:
      name: "memory"
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"80":{"name": "myapp-neg"}}}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: myapp
```

Comment: any update on this ? below answer resolve your issue? feel free to update

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `periodSeconds`: How often (in seconds) to perform the probe. Default to 10 seconds. Minimum value is 1.

So if you set the `periodSeconds` very less like `1` K8s will check the status of POD every 1 second, very frequently and there could be chances you wont get the 500 response.

As soon as the application stops giving **200** at the endpoint K8s will mark the **POD** unready and no more traffic will get routed to it.

Comment: Nice. But I can't see how it would help with the terminating pods as it seems they are not shutting down gracefully. Also, should I set a higher or lower periodSeconds?

Comment: for gracefull shutting down pod you have to configure the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` read at https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

Comment: you should set lower periodSeconds so it quickly check application second on every 1 second or 2 second so there wont be downtime as readiness probe will mark pod unready quickly.